# adding singular plural combinations to SpaCy

Tags: spacy

How do I add new lemmas to SpaCy. For instance, new singular-plural nouns.

Example: 
Kirana = Singular
Kiranas = Plural

I want to add it to SpaCy so that when a sentence contains "Kiranas", Kirana will show up as its lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the word "kirana" to the _nouns.py file which is located inside the Spacy installation folder:(spacy/en/lemmatizer/_nouns.py). When you are adding the word to the file, the text format inside the file should not be changed. Since the lemmatization rules are already defined this should work as you intended.